# Is it possible to keep Flutter windows app in fullscreen?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Is it possible to run the Flutter Windows app in full screen mode all the time? Window resizing causes the application to break by causing the elements to not render properly. To prevent the user from resizing the screen, I want to disable it. Is there a way to keep the application open in full screen all of the time on windows??

Comment: in addition to the accepter answer, here's the official package that helped me https://pub.dev/packages/window_manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line of code in `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  window_size:
     git:
#       url: git://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding.git
       url: https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding
       path: plugins/window_size
```

then add this code in `main.dart`

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:window_size/window_size.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (Platform.isWindows) {
    setWindowMaxSize(Size(1100, 710));
    setWindowMinSize(const Size(1100, 710));
    Future<Null>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 0), () {
      setWindowFrame(
          Rect.fromCenter(center: Offset(650, 350), width: 1000, height: 710));
    });
  }
  runApp(
    (MySplashApp()),
  );
}
```